# Why qrencode unable to generate PNG image

Tags: bash, archlinux, arm64

My operating system is **CoreELEC**

```sh
$ uname -a
$ Linux CoreELEC 4.9.113 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 21 01:00:42 CEST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

My cpu arch is **aarch64**

```sh
$ arch
$ aarch64
```

**qrencode** is ok

```sh
$ qrencode -V
$ qrencode version 4.0.2
```

But, I can't use it to generate PNG images, like this:

```sh
$ qrencode -o /storage/pictures/a.png "LDL6867PM1S3KV9G111A"
$ PNG output is disabled at compile time. No output generated.
```

If anyone knows what the problem is, please let me know, thank you very much!!!

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ I'm sure there is a better forum in the Stack Exchange network for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

When you are building from source and you run the `./configure` step, what it does is checks to see the capabilities of the system before running the `make` step.

If you looked at what it output when you ran `./configure` as you were building qrencode you would have seen something like this:

```
checking for png... no

!!!!!!!!!!
LIBPNG is required to build the utility tools. Temporarily disabled.
!!!!!!!!!!
```

so it's telling you that you are missing libpng and therefore it's going to disable png output.  So while you have built qrencode, your binary has png output disabled which isn't particularly helpful.

When you attempted to run your new qrencode binary and got this error message:

```
PNG output is disabled at compile time. No output generated.
```

It was just informing you that your binary was compiled with png output disabled because as far as `./configure` could tell, libpng wasn't available on your system.

To solve this, install libpng then go back and re-build your qrencode binary - checking to make sure the `./configure` step correctly finds libpng.